# Way to Extract list of elements from Scala list

Tags: scala, search, scala-collections

I have standard list of objects which is used for the some analysis. The analysis generates a list of Strings and i need to look through the standard list of objects and retrieve objects with same name.

```
  case class TestObj(name:String,positions:List[Int],present:Boolean)
  val stdLis:List[TestObj]

  //analysis generates a list of strings
  var generatedLis:List[String]

  //list to save objects found in standard list
  val lisBuf = new ListBuffer[TestObj]()

  //my current way
  generatedLis.foreach{i=>
    val temp = stdLis.filter(p=>p.name.equalsIgnoreCase(i))
    if(temp.size==1){
      lisBuf.append(temp(0))
    }
  }
```

Is there any other way to achieve this. Like having an custom indexof method that over rides and looks for the name instead of the whole object or something. I have not tried that approach as i am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use mutable containers to filter sequences.

Naive solution:

```
val lisBuf =
  for {
    str <- generatedLis
    temp = stdLis.filter(_.name.equalsIgnoreCase(str))
    if temp.size == 1
  } yield temp(0)
```

if we discard condition `temp.size == 1` (i'm not sure it is legal or not):

```
val lisBuf = stdLis.filter(s => generatedLis.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase(s.name)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
stdLis.filter(testObj => generatedLis.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase(testObj.name)))
```

- use [filter](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@filter%28p:A=%3EBoolean%29:Repr) to filter elements from 'stdLis' per predicate
- use [exists](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@exists%28p:A=%3EBoolean%29:Boolean) to check if 'generatedLis' has a value of ....

Comment: We should filter `stdLis` but `generatedLis`